# tensorflow requested = float64_ref, actual = float64

Tags: tensorflow, type-conversion, recurrent-neural-network

I am just trying to get a simple RNNCell to work. This simple code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.Variable(np.ones((2, 3)))
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    out, state = BasicRNNCell(4)(x, x)
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 38, in <module>
    g, _ = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(2)(x, x)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 199, in __call__
    output = self._activation(_linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 903, in _linear
    "Matrix", [total_arg_size, output_size], dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1022, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 849, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 345, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 330, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 676, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 215, in __init__
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 288, in _init_from_args
    initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 666, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 280, in _initializer
    dtype, seed=seed)
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 232, in random_uniform
    minval = ops.convert_to_tensor(minval, dtype=dtype, name="min")
  File "/Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 671, in convert_to_tensor
    dtype.name, ret.dtype.name))
RuntimeError: min: Conversion function <function _constant_tensor_conversion_function at 0x112053c08> for type <type 'object'> returned incompatible dtype: requested = float64_ref, actual = float64
```

This is the output of `pip show tensorflow`:

> Metadata-Version: 2.0
>     Name: tensorflow
>     Version: 0.11.0rc1
>     Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
>     Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
>     Author: Google Inc.
>     Author-email: opensource@google.com
>     Installer: pip
>     License: Apache 2.0
>     Location: /Users/ethan/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>     Requires: mock, protobuf, numpy, wheel, six
>     Classifiers:
>       Development Status :: 4 - Beta
>       Intended Audience :: Developers
>       Intended Audience :: Education
>       Intended Audience :: Science/Research
>       License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
>       Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
>       Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics
>       Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
>       Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries
>     Entry-points:
>       [console_scripts]
>       tensorboard = tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard:main

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TensorFlow, class Tensor has dtype of float64_ref and class Variable has dtype of float64. And BasicRNNCell need a Tensor other than a Variable as inputs.
In your code, 
`x = tf.Variable(...)`
 should be changed to 
`x = tf.convert_to_tensor(...)`

Comment: Confirmed that your solution worked, but it's a little confusing to me. Why can't it take a variable as input?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug in Tensorflow and I invite you to [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

To workaround this issue, you can use `tf.identity` to create a `float64_ref` instead of the `float64` `x` and pass this value as the `inputs` parameter.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.Variable(np.ones((2, 3)))
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    out, state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(4)(tf.identity(x), x)
```

Comment: Finally got around to opening the issue. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Is there a real solution to this? I get the same error, and even simple code causes this:
`>>> import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                        
>>> tf.Variable(initial_value=[0.0], dtype=tf.float64) 
`

Comment: What tf version are you using? With the latest I have no problem running your code